# System recursion limit getting bypassed?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to wrap my head around recursion and have a question. On my machine, `sys.getrecursionlimit()` gives `1000`, which means I can call a function recursively at most 1000 times. However, I'm able to run the following code successfully:

```
def sum_badly(S, start, stop):
    if start == stop:
        return S[start]
    else:
        return sum_badly(S, start, (start+stop)//2) + sum_badly(S, (start+stop)//2 + 1, stop)

MAX = 100000
S = range(MAX)
print(sum_badly(S, 0, MAX-1))
```

This finishes almost instantaneously, and gives me the expected answer of `4999950000`. However, how is it that my program is able to bypass the recursion limit of `1000` calls?

Comment: Why do you think it's making more than 1000 recursive calls?

Comment: @user2357112 Very interesting question! For an input size that well exceeds 1000, doesn't the first half of the call after `return` consume `1000` calls?

Comment: @user2357112 Ah! So you're saying this is more like binary search, and I'm actually making `log 100000`  = 16 calls in each half?

Comment: The recursion limit is a limit on the depth of the call stack; sibling branches of a recursive call tree don't count against each other's recursion limit.

Comment: @user2357112 Okay . . . that's nice to know, but I'm not sure I get the picture 100% correctly. Can I find a visualization somewhere? How are sibling branches defined? Would be awesome if you could give me a link.

Comment: See the tree in [this link](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/chapter1/node13.html), representing the calls made by a recursive Fibonacci implementation? The left side and the right side of that tree would be sibling branches.

Comment: @user2357112 So you're saying that what matters is how many times the function by a given name has been called in the current stack, and that the `+` doesn't, by itself, add up recursion depths?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the name is. If you wrote 2000 functions `f1` through `f2000` and had `f1` call `f2` and so on, you'd hit the "recursion limit", even though there's no actual recursion going on. It's just a limit on how deep the call stack is allowed to get, to prevent stack overflows.

Comment: @user2357112 Superb! I'll always remain grateful for your help here. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the 'recursion depth' of your code is only log_2(100000) (approx) which is cca 17.

Of course, you are doing much more recursion calls, but in no time more than 17 calls are on the stack simultaneously (well, probably little bit more because of rounding errors)

Nice way how to verify this:
- create global variable `depth`
- increase `depth` by one any time sum_badly begins
- decrease `depth` by one any time sum_badly ends

now, you can examine what is the maximum value of `depth` and why.

Comment: Thanks! The same thing struck me while discussion in the comments. Silly me. :-)

Comment: More like doodling! :D I'll accept this as answer as soon as the system lets me.